# Populating a tags database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, tags

I'm trying to populate the tag database for a rails app that I'm making. Does anyone know where I can find a list of several hundred common tags that I can pre-populate my database with.

I'm using http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields and would like to have it pre-populated since it's hard to have people add new tags on the fly.

Comment: Right now I'm planning on scraping the titles used on a college website to get me started ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started a github project to put a good library together. If you would like to contribute it's at: https://github.com/cyrusstoller/Initial-Tag-Library